# Naming convention for asynchronous getter

Tags: javascript, callback, naming-conventions, getter

For synchronous getter functions, the naming convention is well-defined:

```
var getFerby = function(){
    ..
    return ferby;
};
```

However, if the ferby I want is not locally (synchronously) available, a common method is to handle that situation with a callback:

```
/**
 * Asynchronously gets a ferby and passes it to the callback.
 *  
 *     Once the ferby is retrieved, these rules MUST be followed:
 *       1) Don't feed it after midnight.
 *       2) Don't give it water.
 *       3) Don't let it near bright light.  
 *
 * @param {ferbyCallback} callback - The callback function that expects a ferby.
 */
var fooFerby = function(callback){
    getFerbyLoader().load(function(ferby){
        callback(ferby);
    });
};

/**
 * The callback for the fooFerby function.
 *
 * @callback ferbyCallback
 * @param ferby The ferby
 */
```

What is a good naming convention for `fooFerby` so that I know by name that it expects a callback?

Comment: i like getFerbyCB, _getFerby, cbGetFerby, or getFerbyAsync...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the suggestions.  Personally, I like the prefixes so you only have to look at the front of the name to get the general feel for the function, so `_getFerby` and `cbGetFerby` would be candidates for that.  Looking at [synonyms for get](http://thesaurus.com/browse/get), some more candidates are `acquireFerbie`, `grabFerby`, `obtainFerbie`, `procureFerbie`, or (my personal favorite) `fetchFerby`.  I was hoping for a semi-standardized naming convention for this.

Answer (score 5):

I use the prefix "fetch", instead of "get" for asynchronous getters.

The idea is that if it is not locally available, you need to fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

.NET uses BeginDoAction. I like the same approach in JavaScript. So in your case, the function would be `beginGetFerby`.

NodeJs takes the convention that most methods are asynchronous, and the synchronous methods have a 'Sync' suffix, e.g. doActionSync. You could do the opposite, and have an 'Async' suffix, so your function would be `getFerbyAsync`. I like that approach too.